# Difference between ClientFactory and ClientBuilder in JAX-RS

Tags: jax-rs, webservices-client

What's the difference between creating a new `Client` instance using
`ClientFactory` and `ClientBuilder` in JAX-RS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ClientFactory` class does not exist in the Client API, introduced in JAX-RS 2.0. Have a look at the [`javax.ws.rs.client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/package-summary.html) package.

The `ClientFactory` class was present in the release candidates and milestones of the JAX-RS 2.0 specification, but was replaced with the [`ClientBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html) class. For more details, you can check the old versions of the [`javax.ws.rs-api`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api) artifact.

To create [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) instances, use [`ClientBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html):

```java
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
```